# request handler for task of queue app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

i am adding the task in the push queue that are adding correctly, but in logs there is error, it says that
**No handlers matched this URL.** although my task are added in the queue correctly
my qs is

1. i have to give the url for folder in which servlet present or the url for servle?
2. how to access the parameter of the task.
   `queue.add(withUrl("/SendMail").param("email",input1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you specify should have a corresponding mapping in your web.xml. So, for example /SendMail should have a servlet that it maps to.

The params are available as request parameters in your servlet doGet/doPost method.